# Google-cloud-sdk dnf/yum repo multiple gpgkey errors

Tags: centos, centos7, fedora, google-cloud-platform, rhel7

The google-cloud-sdk repo file for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 and CentOS 7 contains two gpgkey URLs. This is what the repo file looks like:

```
[google-cloud-sdk]
name=Google Cloud SDK
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/cloud-sdk-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
       https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
```

Source: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads

The package managers DNF and YUM are able to use this repo. Other default applications which use repo files such as `PackageKit-command-not-found` and `gnome-software` receive the following 404 error:

```
Failed to search for file: Status code: 404 for https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg;https:/packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in `PackageKit` and `gnome-software`. You should report it to the developers. What is the question here?

Comment: My question is if this is a bug or incorrectly formatted repo file.

Answer (score 4):

Manual page for `dnf.conf` says:

> **gpgkey** list of strings

and list is defined as

> **list**   It is an option that could represent one or more strings separated by space or comma characters.

Therefore from the DNF/Yum point of view, the syntax is not correct (but accepted). You can try to modify the file to have the values separated by space or comma, which might help:

```
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg,https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
```

If it does, it is a bug in Google Cloud offering this invalid repo.

Comment: Seperating the gpgkey URLs by a comma, space or newline does not resolve the issue. If I place only a comma or newline between the two URLs I get status code 404, only a space gives status code 400.

Comment: Then it is a bug in PackageKit.

Comment: This worked for me on Fedora Silverblue